# Vba Access .mde file conversion

Tags: ms-access

I have a .mde file and need to convert it into .mdb file as I'm trying to upgrade the file to a higher version.

Please let me know the procedure to convert the required files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By definition, the VBA code is not available in MDE/ACCDE files because it has been compiled. There are third party products available for converting MDE and ACCDE files back to MDB and ACCDB formats, including the recovery/decompilation of VBA code. If you search "retrieve vba code from mde," the results will point you to some of those products.

Comment: Hi John, do we have a software that can convert .mde to .mdb file. I 'm not looking for online converter

Answer (score 0):

Contact *Wayne Phillips* at [EverythingAccess](http://www.everythingaccess.com/mdeconversion.asp).

However, you will have to present proper documentation for the ownership of the application, or he won't touch it.